# ssl installing error nginx service. error no such file

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx

this my nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 8001;
}

server {
    server_name my_domain;
    listen 443 ssl;

   # ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /et/ssl/my_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my_key.key;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

and here is the error I am getting

```
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/my_cert.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/my_cert.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

If I restart the service it throws the error code mentioned above. ssl folder exists for sure. I do not know where I am doing wrong. I searched for the answer but I could not find can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: there is a typo in directory name, try changing `/ect/ssl/my_cert.crt` to `/etc/ssl/my_cert.crt`

Comment: thank you but it did no help now my new error like this
```nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/my_cert.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/my_cert.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed```